# RunDLL32 URLDownloadToFile

Tags: windows, winapi, download, rundll32

I'm trying to perform a one-liner file download in Windows command line, without depending on external tools like WGET, or even writing PowerShell or VBScripts scripts.

I tried to run

```
c:\> RunDLL32.exe URLMon.dll,URLDownloadToFIle 0,"http://www.example.com/file.pdf" "c:\\MyName\\Downloads\\",0
```

It didn't work.
What did I do wrong?
Or would that even work?

Answer (score 5):

The function [URLDownloadToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the following signature:

```
HRESULT URLDownloadToFile(
         LPUNKNOWN            pCaller,
         LPCTSTR              szURL,
         LPCTSTR              szFileName,
         DWORD dwReserved,
         LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK lpfnCB
         );
```

Functions callable by rundll32.exe need to have the following function prototype:

```
void CALLBACK  EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

You aren't able to use rundll32.exe to run URLDownloadToFile, because these two prototypes are incompatible.